# Give single value to scanf that require two behaive strange

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x,y; 
  printf("please input 2 numbers:\n");
  scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);
  printf("Now the value for x is %d, and value for y is %d",x,y);
  return 1;
}
```

what I input two numbers and seperated them by `,` then things works as expected.

But if I give one number 2345, then a strange result occured:

Now the value for x is 3456, and value for y is 32767

I can't figure out why it is.

Comment: Why are you returning `1`? it means failure.

Comment: This is undefined behaivor. But scanf might be reading the value to store in y from the top of the stack.

Comment: `x` and `y` have undefined values before the call to `scanf()`. Set them to `0` or to `-1` or to any other _known_ value and then see what happens after the call to `scanf()`.

Comment: I agree. It could be that those numbers pre-existed the call to `scanf`. But either way I'm not surprised that you got weird values.

Comment: @JSN Yeah, I opened this up in my debugger and it's pulling in a value from the wrong stack frame.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if the input 2345 would really yield a result of x=3456 and y=32767? I'm doubtful about the result. – ChinoCarloSedilla 20 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

When you call `scanf()`, you must check the return value of that function to see whether it succeeded or not. On my system, it is documented to return the number of input item assigned.

Comment: Why *On your system*? the documentation don't follow the C std?

Comment: @Jack I wish I could upvote twice. Seriously, why would you tell us about your system? Tell us what the standard says.

Comment: My system happens to follow the standard, at least in this instance. I recommend the OP check with their *own* system, because the value 32767 leads me to believe that they *might* be using a 16-bit system, which *might* follow different (older) rules. For example, some old pre-standard runtime libraries would return the number of *characters* accepted by `scanf()`, not the number of arguments converted (yes, these were hard to work with).

Answer (score 1):

This strange value, is *memory garbage*. In C,all uninitialized variables(except `static` and `extern`) points to memory garbage.
When you use the value of this variable, anything can happen, you have an [`UB`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).You must initialize the values of this variables and check the return-value from [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).

As @Michael Dorst mentioned on comments, set `x` and `x` to some uncomum values(e.g, -1) and after `scanf()` call, check if the values of them have changed too.

Comment: Uninitialized objects have indeterminate value (C 1999 6.7.8 10). This does not cause undefined behavior as defined by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your scanf statement.
Usually, scanf statements have this kind of format:

```
scanf("%d %d",&x,&y); //without the commas inside the ""'s
```

But you have made this format:

```
scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y); //with the commas inside the ""'s
```

which means that you need a comma separator between the two inputs.

---

Look at the following trials 
TRIAL1:(note: input is 2345)

```
Please input 2 numbers:
2345
Now the value for x is 2345, and value for y is 134513867.
```

TRIAL2: (note: input is 23,45)

```
Please input 2 numbers:
23,45
Now the value for x is 23, and the value for y is 45.
```

TRIAL3: (note: input is 23+45)

```
Please input 2 numbers:
23+45
Now the value for x is 23, and the value for y is 134513867.
```

So, according to the trials, the **scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);** requires the input to have a comma separator. What happened to the output for the first and third trial is that, the y variable did contain garbages because these y values are left unchanged/uninitialized. But it seems that the x variable got the correct value because of the first %d on your scanf.